# Trying to get the desired DataFrames from optimized groupby methods

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, ipython, dataframe

I am trying to create smaller DataFrames out of this bigger DataFrame by calling `df.groupby('index_column').max()` and `df.groupby('index_column').min()`, where `index_column` is the column of `df` that I want to now it to be the index of the new Min and Max DataFrames. In these Min and Max DataFrames, I would like to have just 2 simple columns, one index column, and the other column that contains only the Max and Min values respectively.

Putting all that I said above in context, I will use examples from what I have done:

The main DataFrame, `df`, looks like this in Standard Output:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
         name                                          parameter  cycles  \
0       dfmul  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...     159   
1       dfdiv  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...    1335   
2       mpeg2  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...    1992   
3         aes  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...   5441   
4        mips  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...    4263   
5       dfadd  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...     455   
6       dfsin  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...   39589      
..        ...                                                ...     ...    
403     adpcm  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...   23355   
404     dfadd  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...     599   
405       sha  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...  348417   
406  blowfish  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...  251877   
407      jpeg  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...  766742   

    mem_cycles  build_number  
0         None          1300  
1         None          1300  
2         None          1300  
3         None          1300  
4         None          1300  
..         ...           ...  
401       None          1344  
402       None          1344  
403       None          1344  
404       None          1344  
405       None          1344  
406       None          1344  
407       None          1344  

[408 rows x 5 columns]

In [4]:
```

When I call the `max()` and `min()` methods after `groupby('build_number')` I get the following DataFrames that contain the same columns that were present in `df` as you can see:

```
In [5]: df.groupby('build_number').max()
Out[5]: 
             name                                          parameter  cycles  \
build_number                                                                   
1300          sha  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...  348417   
1301          sha  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...  348417   
1302          sha  [["scheduler_type", "sdc"], ["max_chain_delay"...  348417   

# And it continues so on, won't list the whole frame

              mem_cycles  
build_number              
1300                 NaN  
1301                 NaN  
1302                 NaN  
# And it continues so on, won't list the whole frame

In [6]:
```

The same thing is true when I do `min()`.

However, all I want back is a DataFrame that has just `build_number` as an index column, and `cycles` as it only non-index column. In fact, this desired output format is what I get if I call the `mean()` groupby method instead.

```
In [6]: df.groupby('build_number').mean()
Out[6]: 
                     cycles
build_number               
1300           42966.500000
1301           42992.000000
1302           42989.900000
1303           42985.300000

# And it continues so on, won't list the whole frame

In [7]:
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I get my output to be what I want it to be (which is the format when `mean()` is called) when I call `min()` and `max()`?
2. Why is it that when I call `mean()`, the resulting DataFrame had all other non-numeric columns eliminated, but `min()` and `max()` does not eliminate those other non-numeric columns?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is to **filter** the result with your desired **columns**, like so:

**Edit:** as pointed by @cwharland, more efficient to filter cycles before applying **max() / min()**

```
df.groupby('build_number')['cycles'].max()
```

and,

```
df.groupby('build_number')['cycles'].min()
```

The reason why using **mean()** will only show the `cycles` column is because **mean** does not have a definition to get the mean of **String** like in `parameters`, mean is an average of those records by `cycles` whereas **max()** and **min()** will only return a single record (the maximum / minimum), thus all columns within that record is shown, does it make sense?

**Updated:** to make this more clear, **Numeric** values in each field can perform their own with mean/max/min operations and return the value accordingly, **String**, however will only have max/min, ordering lexicographically like `'A' < 'C'`, `'Z' > 'B'` etc. but it cannot perform a mean() operation because it isn't numeric.
All individual columns will return it's own max/min/mean after `groupby` only if they're applicable.

*As a side note*: the filtered **max()** and **min()** result will be more likely a **Series** than **DataFrame**.

So to get a new **DataFrame** from the result, you just need to do:

```
df_max = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('build_number')['cycles'].max())
df_min = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('build_number')['cycles'].min())
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Or, for speed you can simply act on the only column you wish to have in the result: `df_max = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('build_number').cycles.max()`

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick response and help! @Anzel about your answer to my second question, I think I roughly get what you mean, however I need to clarify that I understand you correctly. So you mean to say that for `max()` and `mean()`, these methods will return back a entire row of values with all its columns that correspond to the value that is maximum or minimum?

Comment: @Anzel if that is the case, then what happens if I have a DataFrame where there is more than one column that has numerical values? Like for example, what if in my DataFrame above, `mem_cycles` was not `NaN` and had values instead? Then how are `max()` and `min()` supposed to work to return me the appropriate record that has the right values I need?

Comment: @AKKO, I've updated my answer to provide a more detailed explanation, not so in-depth, but the point is, only **numeric** values can have its **mean()**, **string** can have **max/min** due to lexicographical order, but not **mean**. All individual columns will return it's own max/min/mean after `groupby` only if they're applicable

Comment: @Anzel Ah yes that makes sense now. So the max and min will operate on each column respectively so what I get back in the DataFrame for each record is actually the max and min values for each column respectively according to the index I have specified in `groupby`.  So the gist here is that min and max operate independently on each column.

Comment: @AKKO, absolutely correct, just need to remember the part why **String** has max/min but *NOT* mean -- only numeric values have mean :)